# Is there an index number to use when using jQuery upon matched set of DOM element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering if there is an index number to use when using jQuery to manipulate DOM.

For example can I do something like

```
$("#elements a").css('id','element-'+index);
```

So to turn

```
<div id="elements">
  <a href="#"></a>
  <a href="#"></a>
  <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

to

```
<div id="elements">
  <a id="element-1" href="#"></a>
  <a id="element-2" href="#"></a>
  <a id="element-3" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: `.css('id','element-'+index);` Why are you even using the `css` method???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you want to set the id attribute then you need to user [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
$("#elements a").attr('id',function(index){
    return 'element-'+ (index + 1)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/UMdRs/)

Answer (score 1):

Arun's method will work just fine, but so will this and it seems a little simpler in concept because `.each()` passes the callback the index of the item it's enumerating so you can use that directly to just assign the `id` value:

```
$("#elements a").each(function(index) {
    this.id = 'element-'+ (index + 1);
});
```

---

Or, if you're trying to just reference the 3rd item without assigning an id ahead of time, you can do that like this:

```
$("#elements a").eq(2).css("color", "red");
```

Answer (score 0):

do it like this..

```
var i=1;    
$("#elements a").each(function(){
      $(this).attr("id","element-"+i);
       i++;
});
```

Comment: First off, `.each` can pass the `index` right into the function, so why use another variable to do this?

Comment: What is the point of using `.each` when [`.attr` can already pass you the index](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr)?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 `.each()` passes you the index too... http://api.jquery.com/each/#each1

Comment: @Ian - But now you have to call `$` twice the time you needed.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I wasn't trying to argue against you, I was just pointing out that `.each()` passes the index (like the first comment on this answer says). And if you're actually worried about having to call `$` twice, then it can be `this.id = "element-" + i;`. For a simple attr change, using `.attr()` probably makes sense. For multiple changes or generic looping, `.each()` probably makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to access a certain anchor element based on the last number in the ID?
If so, just loop through the elements returned by `$("#elements").find('a')` and test the ID against something. Like this:

```
var d = document.createElement('div');
var search = 1;
d.id = "elements";
d.innerHTML = '<a id="element-1" href="#"></a> <a id="element-2" href="#"></a> <a id="element-3" href="#"></a>';

$(d).find('a').each(function (index, item) {
    if (parseInt(item.id.split('-')[1]) == search)
        alert("got it");
});
```